TPS65131 inverting dc-dc overshoot
I am trying to make a ±12 V power supply with a TPS65131 DC-DC converter.
The positive rail looks just fine, but the negative rail overshoots to around -12.7 V and then slowly recovers to -12 V, then the process repeats. Increasing the output capacitors just slows down the process. Here is the oscillogramm with a 330 μF capacitor:

The schematic I am using is pretty much the same as the datasheet, so I assume that the problem is with the PCB.
Here are the schematic and the PCB:



What causes this behaviour? I understand that my PCB layout is nothing like the datasheet recommends, but I am interested in the reason.
What is the problem with my PCB exactly?
Can it be fixed without layout changes, with component changes?


It's not overshoot, just apply some load and it will go away. Alternatively you can try slowing down the control loop or playing with soft start. But most probably just load will sort it out.

@TQQQ just tried adding a 1.2kOhm load resistor, didn't help - it just sped up the frequency.

Is that load? 1A is load :) If it's a very low current supply, you need to tweak C22 maybe
https://content.imageresizer.com/images/memes/Crocodile-Dundee-Knife-meme-10.jpg

@TQQQ You mean C28?

C28 too, but i would start with C22.

@TQQQ But C22 affects only the positive rail, the positive one is just fine.

Right... You made me read the datasheet now. So he's, C28 could work too. But without a compensation network outside don't expect much improvement. The point is to slow things down, reduce bandwidth. C28 is not that, it's feed forward. If you have a very light load, consider adding a load resistor, some 100R, maybe even 47R

@TQQQ 100 Ohms dropped the voltage a lot, to around -3 volts. Something's very fishy with this converter.

Ooohh, that's strange. Well, try 300R.

Have you found the solution?

@TQQQ Unfortunately, no. But I've ordered another PCB with everything re-routed like in the datasheet and somehow it works.

The converter has entered "power saving mode" for light loads. Other devices call this "burst-mode".
TQQQ's comment is correct. Increasing the load to a certain threshold will switch the operation to continuous conduction mode.
As noticed in your comment, A moderate increase in load current will reduce the cycle time resulting in an increase in ripple frequency.
"Burst-mode operation" was introduced  into several SMPS devices to reduce battery consumption under light loads when duty cycle cannot be reduced further.
These devices control output voltage and respond to load current changes by sending charge pulses. When the charge contained in a pulse cannot be reduced by narrowing the pulse, the pulse train is turned off until the output voltage drops too low, then it turns on again. This causes the output voltage to increase. Then the pulse train is turned off again.
If a ripple-free output is more important than battery life then an appropriate resistance can be added as a load. Some devices (including this one) can disable burst-mode with a pin setting.

Edit: The negative side does enter DCM mode under light load which will produce this ripple, but the frequency should remain the same as the load changes. The duty cycle will change though. So your circuit/layout may be fine. You still need more load current to obtain CCM. The datasheet should help you understand what load current is required to maintain CCM.

PSP and PSN pins are low. It's turned off?

Nevertheless @sx107 , the information provided indicates power saving mode. Perhaps PSN has a connection difficulty.

It's not the PCB.
If you have 330uF cap with 0.7V ripple that drops in 60ms, you have only about 3.8mA load.
The chip swiches to DCM at such light load, which means it only occasionally tops up the negative voltage and you get more ripple. What is not shown that if the topping up is a single switching pulse or multiple.
Also your schematic is missing the chip supply filter, 100 ohm series resistor between VIN and 5V.

TPS65131 has a pin to turn on/off the low-power mode. It's turned off, PSN pin is low.
